# Openwrt + coova chilli

Tags: openwrt, coovachilli

Openwrt with coova-chilli as a captive portal is working fine when the device is configured in Router mode.
We are trying to make it work in AP mode where the device is just network extension bridge.
By doinf DHCPgateway and dhcp relay agent client connect to that SSID got an IP address from the backend server. But pop page/ splace page is not appeatrs on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect coova-chilli router to other routers and that other routers in AP mode.

Comment: Thanks Vishal, But after checking the code, we found it might not possible to run a chilli as we are trying. As even if we use relay agent chilli refers its internet IP for the client instead of DHCP IP.